# Create a pull request comment in a repo with no issues using the GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

According to the [GitHub v3 API for pull requests](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/)

> Comments on pull requests can be managed via the Issue Comments API.

In the Issues API I should be able to [create a comment](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment) with

> POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number/comments

Unfortunately the repo I'm working with has Issues disabled so when I try that, I get the 410 error message

> Issues are disabled for this repo

How can I create a pull request comment in a repo with no issues using the GitHub API?

Comment: [Here's an example curl request](https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/b7c70419527236ba0f6b) that creates a comment on an Pull Request in a repository that has Issues disabled.

In other words, it should Just Work™, but it sounds like you're running into some speed-bumps.

Can you post an example curl command showing the full request and response that you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you browse to?:

```
https://github.com/:owner/:repo/issues
```

If you get a 404 there, then it sounds like you just need to enable Issues under Features on the repo's settings page:

```
https://github.com/:owner/:repo/settings
```

Edit: Ah, you don't want to work with issues at all. Instead of working with an issue number, you need to work with the pull request number, and simply post a comment that way:

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/comments

{
  "body": "Nice change",
  "commit_id": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
  "path": "file1.txt",
  "position": 4
}
```

See the [Pull Request Review Comments API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/) for more.

Comment: I can but enabling issues isn't a good solution in this case. :(